# What changes does the Starbow mod make to units, spells, and tech trees?

Tags: starcraft-2, starbow

There's recently been a lot of hype about Starbow and I've been playing the mod plenty. However, it would be nice to be able to read about changes, unit tweaks, and new spells while not in the game so I can think about them casually. What are the changes made to SC2 and Brood War units, tech trees, and the like for this mod?

Comment: Not sure why this was VtC'd - it's a solid question (even if it is "just" a compilation of data) with as far as my minor googling/reading of TL can show, no source of an answer as of yet.

Comment: "Too broad" was the reason given, an I'm inclined to agree with it. An answer to this would be an exhaustive list of the features of the mod.

Comment: I disagree with the VtC, this is obviously a relevant discussion and the place to have it.